# gallery clicked item android

Tags: android, methods, click, gallery, slide

I have gallery and it is sliding.

```
public void run() {
    PicPosition = agallery.getSelectedItemPosition() +1;  
    if (PicPosition == text.length)     {
        PicPosition=0;
        gallery.setSelection(PicPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        gallery.setSelection(PicPosition);//move to the next gallery element.
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //execute every second
}
```

Okey, then I want to know the clicked item by user. In my run method, the items select automatically (not by user). But if the user clicks an item, How can I know that item? I cannot use `onItemSelected` method because of this automatic slide. I can use `onClick` method, but how? Please help me.